# Rails map method with link_to helper combined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, view-helpers

I have a model where I want all the records for the association , separated by 'and' and being displayed as a link ... So far I have a map or a link_to option in mind .... but I would like to combine both:

My desired result is this:

`name` and `name2` and `name3` etc. each being displayed as a link.

so

[name...](/name) and [name...](/name2)

The association works fine and gives me all entries if I do

```
= model.associations.map(&:name).join(' and ')
```

But 'map' does not work as a link.
Is it possible to somehow combine `map` and `link_to` ?

For link_to I would use ..:

```
-model.associations.each do |a|
  =link_to a.name, a
```

This obviously would not separate the association entries with an 'and'. 
Any tip is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I just want to display all records as a link like with each.do |a|, =link_to a.name, a => but I want all links to be separated by an 'and' EXCEPT the last link should not have an 'and' after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
= model.associations.map { |a| link_to(a.name, a) }.join("&nbsp;and&nbsp;").html_safe
```

But, I'd divide the logic between action and view. In the action

```
@items = model.associations
```

In the view

```
= @items.map { |a| link_to(a.name, a) }.join("&nbsp;and&nbsp;").html_safe
```

Comment: Nice! Works. I hope its not worst practice case. But your solution works very fine! Many thanks!!

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)

Comment: Uh, sei italiano!

Comment: Non sono italiano. Sono tedesco. Grazie lo stesso! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for what you are doing is to just add and after the `=link_to a.name, a`. Since you are only outputting the data in a template, and not saving it in a variable for reuse later, there is no need for a map

Comment: Thx. How do I prohibit that there will be an 'and ' after the last record? I mean when the .each loop ends I don't want an 'and ' at the end ... Do you understand? Thx!